# Visual (geometric) intuition behind a problem involving vector calculus

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, numerical-methods, vectors, numerical-linear-algebra

The following problem is inspired and directly taken from *A preconditioner for solving the inner problem of the p-version of the FEM* by Sven Beuchler.

I am trying to find a numerical solution of the following model problem.

$$-\Delta u=f\\u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$$
in the domain $\Delta =(-1,1)^2$. We can solve the above using the $p-$ version of the FEM with only one element $\Omega$. As the finite element space, we choose

$$M = \{u \in H^1_0(\Omega), u|_\Omega \in P^p\},$$
where $P^p$ is the space of all polynomials of degree $\leq p$ in both variables.

Now, this problem can be discretized as follows. And I need your help in obtaining a geometric visualization of the following problem.

> Find $u_p\in M$ such that, $$\int_\Omega \nabla u_p \cdot \nabla v_p d(x,y) = \int_\Omega fv_p d(x,y)$$ for all $v_p \in M$.

I only want a visual interpretation of the above quoted problem considering the finite element space $M$ and it's vectors $v_p$. What does it mean to find a $u_p$ amongst $v_p$s such that the above equation holds? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you get your reading from? The task is to find the linear combination $u_p$ of kernel functions so that the integral identity holds for all test functions $v_p$. Here you take the kernel functions that span $M$ also as test functions, so that overall you get a square linear system for the coefficients.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for your comment. As I have mentioned, I have taken everything from the paper mentioned at the beginning of the question. I understand the task is to find a vector among all the $v_p$s that best fit the equation. All I want is a visual understanding as to what this special vector $(u_p)$ might be. Thank you

Comment: $M$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Fixing a basis and writing the equation out for these basis function results in a linear system that can be solved exactly. There is nothing mysterious so far. The alchemy starts when the finite element discretization has tens or hundreds of thousands elements and you want to solve this in blocks, fast, efficient and exact, where you get to the dilemma "fast, cheap, accurate, choose two".